# Delete only if stored procedure input parameter is met

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, sql-delete

I have a stored procedure that deletes a lot of data from multiple tables. The order of deletion is determined by foreign key constraints.

A few delete statements in the procedure shouldn't be executed when my stored procedure input parameter `@P_DeleteIfOnly = 0`.

Whenever I call my stored procedure with 0 (`exec spname 0`), it still deletes the data. I have tried a few different combinations in the query:

First I tried to add the input parameter in a `WHERE` clause, but that didn't work:

```
DELETE blablabla
WHERE @P_DeleteIfOnly = 1
```

Then I tried it with `IF` statements, but that also didn't work:

```
IF (@P_DeleteIfOnly= 1)
BEGIN
    DELETE blablabla
END
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The last bit, with the IF statement, ought to do the trick. At least, that's how I would implement something like this. Can you show us the full code?

Comment: Your code is right. You have bug somewhere else. Try post full code.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Procedural code like stored procedures is **highly vendor-specific**. Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: The procedure has 1 only parameter? Can you show us the first row of your procedure where we can see parameter definition?

Comment: The procedure has two input parameters. It looks like this: `CREATE PROCEDURE Deletion @P_Identification varchar(255) ,@P_DeleteIfOnly int = 0 AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON;`

Comment: Please add the code to the question, instead of in a comment. This makes it easier by having all code in 1 place. Also, the code you added shows nothing extra. Please add the whole code for the procedure (but feel free to anonimize column names, etc). We need to see the relevant parts.

Comment: Declare simple yes/no params as bit: "@P_DeleteIfOnly bit = 0" Add a "print @P_DeleteIfOnly" to see what the value really is.